# Hide Dropdown based on selection of user Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Here **default the state drop down is loaded**
my country dropdown is

```
  <select id="countrydrp" name="countrydrp" class="required" onchange="changeStateType();">
                        <option value="">Select State</option>
                        <option value="US">USA</option>
                        <option value="IN">INDIA</option>
                        //some more options
  </select>
```

my state drop down is

```
 <select id="statedrp" name="statedrp"  style="width: 80px; padding: 5px; height: 30px; width: 215px;" class="" onchange="validteSelected();">
                        <option value="">Select State</option>
                        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                        //some more options
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="statetxt" name="statetxt" class="text" data-error-type="inline" />
```

if user selects option other than US from Country dropdown

I am trying to hide state drop down and show the textbox as given

my Script is

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#statetxt").hide();//i am hiding the textbox on page loads
    }); 

 function changeStateType() {
        debugger;
        var selVal = $("#countrydrp option:selected").val();
        if (selVal == "US") {
            $("#statetxt").hide();
            $("#statedrp").show();
            $("#statedrp").addClass("required");  
        }
        else {
            $("#statetxt").show();
            $("#statedrp").hide();
            $("#statetxt").addClass("required");
        }
    }
```

now the **problem** is both are showing after the i select any country option

**If i Select Tunsia(other than US) Then the dropdown and the textbox appears**[image: I Selected Tunsia Then the dropdown and the textbox appears]

**If i Select United States Then the two dropdowns appears**
[image: I Selected United States Then the two dropdowns appears]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `.val()` along with select selector to get selected option value:

```
var selVal = $("#countrydrp").val();
```

**[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m028vpph/)**

Comment: thanks but both gives the same value either my code or your code @Milind

Comment: @rp3220 you need to remove debugger from your function.

Comment: Thanks !! It is working fine in the demo but it doesnot working in my scenario! I am unable to find the reason i gave images to show you my problem please go through that

Comment: have you wrapped the function in head section. try putting alert inside to check whether the function is even getting called or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```js
$("#countrydrp").on("change", function() {
  //hide state if country is different than US
  $("#statedrp").toggle($(this).val() == "US");
  //show input text if country is different than US
  $("#statetxt").toggle($(this).val() != "US");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="countrydrp" name="countrydrp" class="required" onchange="changeStateType();">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  <option value="US">USA</option>
  <option value="IN">INDIA</option>
</select>
<select id="statedrp" name="statedrp" style="width: 80px; padding: 5px; height: 30px; width: 215px;" class="" onchange="validteSelected();">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="statetxt" name="statetxt" class="text" data-error-type="inline" />
```

Answer (score 0):

get the value using:

```
var selVal = $("#countrydrp").val();
```

not this:

```
 var selVal = $("#countrydrp option:selected").val();// this will also give the same value but not a good one to apply .val();
```

I see your code is already working just remove the debugger;

```
function changeStateType() {
        var selVal = $("#countrydrp option:selected").val();
        if (selVal == "US") {
            $("#statetxt").hide();
            $("#statedrp").show();
            $("#statedrp").addClass("required");  
        }
        else {
            $("#statetxt").show();
            $("#statedrp").hide();
            $("#statetxt").addClass("required");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but both gives the same value either my code or your code @suchit

Comment: you need to remove debugger from your function.

Comment: I know and i have mentioned also in answer.

Comment: sorry i didnt see that @suchit

Comment: why would removing debugger help??